# JQuery file download works in Chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a short piece of JQuery that creates a .M3U file containing only a single string, which it then prompts the user to download. This works fine in Chrome but has no effect in Firefox, and no errors appear on the FireFox console. Can anyone help?

```
function playfile(filepath) {
    var file = document.createElement('a');
    file.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + decodeURIComponent(unescape(filepath)));
    file.setAttribute('download', "Play.m3u");
    file.click();
}
```

Comment: Regarding [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20194533/402037) answer, try adding the link to the DOM

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? I'm struggling to fit the answer in that post with mine, sorry.

Comment: Just add the link to the DOM before actually clicking it `document.body.appendChild(file); file.click();` and remove it afterwards (if needed) `document.body.removeChild(file);`

Comment: Ahh thanks. It's working although the "from" portion in the Firefox download prompt simply says "data:" is there any way I can alter this value, either to an explicit value, or the url of the page (which is localhost)?

Comment: Sorry, but with this question/problem I can't help you...